# How to count 'where' matched records in Laravel query builder

Tags: laravel, query-builder

I'm studying query builder.
Below code works I can get count number however $calccount part looks strange.

HTML view is this

> [{"count(*)":13}]

Could you teach me write code please?

```
 public function s_list()
 {
     $books = DB::table('books')　　//This is works
     ->where('q18a', '=', '5')
     ->get();
     
     $ttlrecordC = Book::count('kid'); //This is works

     $calccount = DB::table('books') //works but looks strange
     ->select(DB::raw('count(*)'))
     ->where('q18a', '=', '5')
     ->get();

     return view('s_list', ['books' =>$books])
     ->with('ttlrecordC',$ttlrecordC)
     ->with('calccount',$calccount);
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the calc method instead of get

```
$calccount = DB::table('books') 
     ->where('q18a', '=', '5')
     ->count();
//if you have models in place
$calccount = Book::where('q18a', '=', '5')->count();
```

for the return view, you can do it like this

```
 return view('s_list', [
    'books' => $books,
    'ttlrecordC' => $ttlrecordC,
    'calccount' => $calccount,
]);
```